# how to pass the dynamic image url to other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to pass the path of image to onclick event. I am taking the image from folder dynamically. Now,I have to pass the path of image. I have tried, but I am not getting expected results. Please give me any advice.

My code:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="img-responsive">
    <img id="prod" src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/store/'.$data->img);?>"  style="height:350px;width:200px;display:none;" alt="Fjords">
</div>
```

My HTML & JS

```
<style type="text/css">
.button
{
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FF8C00;
    box-shadow: -8px 8px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#cover{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    z-index:5;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
}
#loginScreen
{
    height:380px;
    width:340px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    display:none;
    background: url(//here i have to pass above mentioned path src of image) no-repeat;
    border:5px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#loginScreen:target, #loginScreen:target + #cover{
    display:block;
    opacity:2;
}
.cancel
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:3px;
    right:2px;
    background:rgb(245,245,245);
    color:black;
    height:30px;
    width:35px;
    font-size:30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <a href="#loginScreen" class="button">Click here to Log In</a>
</div>
<div id="loginScreen">
    <a href="#" class="cancel">&times;</a>
</div>
<div id="cover" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your javascript?

Comment: I am doing with css only

Comment: What do you want done in a click event? If you aren't going to be using JavaScript, there isn't much you could do.

Comment: Thanks for your response